# ValueError: Cannot serialize: jdatetime.datetime() in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I installed `django-jalali` package in order to be able to use the Jalali calendar. **The package worked well, and I could run it** until I want to change fields that record was already in place.but when I wanted to change that fields I got this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot serialize: jdatetime.datetime(1398, 3, 10, 18, 17, 10, 557480)
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
```

what's wrong? And how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Oh yes, I had exactly the same error, and due to poorly coded and
>   unreadable django by time zone you should not use the default
>   parameter because the migrate file cannot be serialized and you must
>   use the auto_now_add = True parameter.

**you must be set follow params in your settings**

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

example field in model:

```
date_start = jmodels.jDateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="زمان شروع")
```

> and makemigrations again.

Good luck.

Comment: I did change my strategy fot using `datetime` and `date` in my projects. Django recommend to set `UTC` for all `datetime` and `date` in database. Also I recommend to doing like Django. By the way, I will accept your answer because of your try. @evergreen.

Answer (score 0):

***Recommended solution***

I did change my strategy for using `datetime` in `Django` projects. Currenty I use `UTC` and `Aware` datetime in my projects.

**Django Recommend:**

> [Warning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)
>
> Dealing with aware datetime objects isn’t always intuitive. For
>   instance, the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructor
>   doesn’t work reliably for time zones with DST. Using UTC is generally
>   safe; if you’re using other time zones, you should review the pytz
>   documentation carefully.